# clear animation with delay in ImageView

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation in my code. But I want when I click Button my ImageView return to original place(reset animation) I have a method for that. My code is :

```
 private void returnToOriginalRotationState() {
  RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
  animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
  animation.setDuration((long) 2*1000);
  animation.setFillAfter(true);
  animation.setFillEnabled(true);
  imgHeade.startAnimation() }
```

It works as well 
But 
    animation.setDuration((long) 2*1000);

not working !!!

android android-animation

Comment: Perform `imgHeade.setAnimation(animation);` and then run the animation.

Comment: Thanks, I used imgHeade.setAnimation(animation); but animation not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the animation you want to perform?

```
new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
```

It seems that all the degrees are `0.0f`.

Comment: yes, I want to put my ImageVIew in original position, because when I hint a Button ImageView move to new RotateAnimation(0,19,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);     this code works as well

Comment: Now I want to my ImageView come back to original position.

Comment: you need to use 19 somewhere for return animation to work correctly